# Ajax call problems

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I have some problems with my ajax call, I have a collection group and when I click on show link it should show me the collection's tasks.The problem is when I try to create new tasks for the current collection.I made 50% of the problem, because it creates the records in database, but something strange happen.

[Form is already submitted even If I do not click the create button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcicN.png)

After ajax call, it creates the records in database, but it does not append the newly created element, it shows me this:

[Ajax call response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4Z96.png)

Here is my ajax script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        // store task
        $('#create-task').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({

                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: $('#create-task-form').serialize(),

                success: function (data) {
                    $('#create-task-form').trigger('reset');
                    $('#createTaskModal').modal('hide');

                    $('.collections').append('<li>' +  data.name + '</li>');
                }

            });

        });
    });
```

I did not set the url, because when I do that it shows me something like this, and I do not know why.

[Duplicate collection/collection/id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNpmc.png)

[Set the url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79mBE.png)

Routes:

```
// Collection routes
Route::prefix('collections')->middleware('auth')->group(function() {

    Route::get('/', 'CollectionController@index')->name('collections.index');

    Route::post('/', 'CollectionController@store')->name('collections.store');

    Route::get('/{collection}', 'CollectionController@show')->name('collections.show');

    Route::get('/{collection?}/edit', 'CollectionController@edit')->name('collections.edit');

    Route::patch('/{collection?}', 'CollectionController@update')->name('collections.update');

    Route::delete('/{collection?}', 'CollectionController@destroy')->name('collections.destroy');

    Route::post('/{collection?}', 'CollectionController@storeTask')->name('tasks.store');

});
```

Controller

```
 public function storeTask(Request $request)
    {
        $attributes = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|min:3',
            'description' => 'nullable|min:3',
            'status' => 'required',
            'due' => 'nullable|date'
        ]);

        $attributes['collection_id'] = $request->collection;

        $task = Task::create($attributes);

        return Response::json($task);
    }
```

PS: I can still create records, even the validation from back-end fails!

Comment: Where is the CSRF Token?

Comment: 422 is for invalid data. Generally csrf token error is 419 but try to add csrf. if it doesn't fix. Check again your inputs & fill the inputs with validate rules. Be careful for min:3 & required & date

Comment: I have csrf token already, in another script.I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: Even you fix that 422 error. You are probably got 419 because csrf. You need to add here. 
_token: $('#token').val(),
data: $('#create-task-form').serialize()

Comment: Which routes are you using the web.php or api.php?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your image your routing is wrong.

You get a 404 for trying to access collections/collections twice leading to a non existing URL of course.

A solution to this would be:

```
 url: {{ url('/collections/25') }},
```